# Question migrated and my answer is no longer there, but I still got 15 points for an accept

Tags: support, deleted-answers, migrated-questions

I got 15 points for an "accept" today. It was a while since I'd answered the question, so I clicked on the link in my profile to remind myself.

Here's the link from my profile that I clicked on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816301/seo-which-urls-are-the-best/6816457#6816457

It turns out that the question has been migrated from SO to Webmasters.

That's fair enough; it's probably better there, but I posted my answer on SO before it was moved.

What surprises me is that the question now has a different accepted answer, and in fact no longer has my answer at all.

Presumably (given that it was accepted) my answer was reasonable, so I'm surprised that it's been deleted. What's happened to it? Additionally, given that a different answer is now accepted, why have I still got the points for the acceptance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer is [still there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816301/seo-which-urls-are-the-best?noredirect=1) on StackOverflow.

When you write up an answer, it's possible for the question to be closed (or migrated) while you're still working on your post. There is a window of time after the closure when the answer will still get posted. It looks like you managed to post it during that window, so your answer didn't move to Webmasters along with the rest of the answers.

After that, I assume the asker came and accepted your answer on Stack Overflow in addition to the answer they accepted on Webmasters.